# Integrating complex function $f(z)=\sin(z)$ along a path

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, complex-integration

What we learned in complex analysis is

$$\int_{\gamma}f(z)\,dz=\int_{\gamma}(u(x,y)+iv(x,y))(dx+i\,dy)$$

if we let $f(z)=u+iv$ and $dz=dx+i\,dy$.

So how could I calculate $f(z)=\sin(z)$ ? What is the corresponding part of $u$ and $v$ for $f(z)=\sin(z)$?

Comment: How to calculate $\sin z?$ How about using the definition of $\sin z.$

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is to find $$\Re(\sin(z))\quad\text{and}\quad\Im(\sin(z))$$

Plug $z=x+yi$ to get
$$\sin(x+yi)=\sin(x)\cos(yi)+\cos(x)\sin(yi)$$

Now use the formulas $\sin(yi)=i\sinh(y)$ and $\cos(yi)=\cosh(y)$ to get

$$\sin(x+yi)=\underbrace{\sin(x)\cosh(y)}_\text{real part}+i\underbrace{\cos(x)\sinh(y)}_\text{imaginary part}$$

So your corresponding functions are equal to $$u(x,y)=\sin(x)\cosh(y)$$ $$v(x,y)=\cos(x)\sinh(y)$$

Comment: Hi, give me a new view of how to deal with complex sin and cos. Thanks quite a lot!